# vbscript Not able to process Regex

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to use Regex to return matching word in vbscript. My hta file is here at [gist](https://gist.github.com/SanjeetSk/6045a7edece72aa11bde23108a26bc6b)

My vbs Sub is :-

```
Sub ProcessFile(FileName)
On Error Resume Next

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fileObj = fso.GetFile(FileName)
Set contents = fileObj.OpenAsTextStream(1, 0)
'MsgBox contents.ReadAll
        If err.number = 0 then
        Set r = New RegExp
        r.Global = True
        r.Pattern = "\[CATS\]\.(\[[^]]+\])"
        Set ms = r.Execute(contents)
        For Each m In ms
            MsgBox m.SubMatches(0)
            demo.innerHTML = demo.innerHTML & m.SubMatches(0)
        Next

        Else
            MsgBox err.number
        End If
End Sub
```

It doesn't return matching words
There is something miss

For a text file containing following text:-

```
[CATS].[Hello_World1] Lorem Ipsum [CATS].[Hi_Venus1] Demo Text [CATS].[Yo_Moon1] Lorm Ipsum 

[CATS].[Hello_World] Lorem Ipsum [CATS].[Hi_Venus] Demo Text [CATS].[Yo_Moon] Lorm Ipsum
```

It is expected to return `[Hello_World1], [Hi_Venus1], [Yo_Moon1], [Hello_World], [Hi_Venus], [Yo_Moon]`

Comment: And?  Read your question from our perspective.  What are you missing?

Comment: Still clueless....

Comment: What is your question, obviously. We can't read your mind.  What isn't working?

Comment: sorry...... I have updated question, didn't realized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You run your code with an active OERN. That hides errors. E.g: `contents` is a stream (so `contents.ReadAll()` 'works'). But `r.Execute(contents)` can't possibly 'work' because `.Execute` expects/needs a string.

**Update wrt comment:**

If you know that `MsgBox contents.ReadAll` displays the string content of the stream, then `Set ms = r.Execute(contents.ReadAll())` shouldn't be too hard.
Remember: `Set` is used to assign an **object** (stream, match collection, ...) to a variable; so `Set str = contents.ReadAll` can't possibly 'work' (and you'd be told about that if you'd disabled/removed the OERN).

Comment: so any way to do this.. I tried `Set str = contents.ReadAll`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. a lesson I must follow is Always work without OERN.

Comment: @KailashSingh It's first thing you should comment out when debugging issues with the code.

Answer (score 3):

You could also process it line by line using Do...Loop statement.

```
Sub ProcessFile(FileName)

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fileObj = fso.GetFile(FileName)
Set contents = fileObj.OpenAsTextStream(1, 0)
        If err.number = 0 then
        Linenum = 0
        Do Until contents.AtEndOfStream
            line = contents.readline
            Linenum = Linenum + 1
            Set r = New RegExp
            r.Pattern = "\[CATS\]\.(\[[^]]+\])"
            Set ms = r.Execute(line)
                For Each m In ms
                    MsgBox m.SubMatches(0)
                    demo.innerHTML = demo.innerHTML & m.SubMatches(0)
                Next
        Loop    
        Else
            err.clear
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Isnull(ms) = false then` - ms can never be Null and comparing boolean expression against boolean constants is nonsense.